# OctoberCms send message using SMTP server

Tags: laravel, smtp, octobercms

I have some problem. I need send message using SMTP, because I want to set up а password when sending. I read this manual https://octobercms.com/docs/services/mail
But I didn't find how I can set up my password, in this manual sets up only from adress

> $message->from('us@example.com', 'October');

Can your help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set SMTP details inside **config** folder **mail.php** file `config/mail.php` * (you can find **config** folder in **root directory** where you **setup your october CMS**)

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => 'smtp', // drive need to be smtp

    'host' => 'smtp.mailgun.org',

    'port' => 587,

    'from' => ['address' => 'noreply@domain.tld', 'name' => 'OctoberCMS'],

    'encryption' => 'tls',

    'username' => null,

    'password' => null,

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

];
```

set all details here as you like and start using `SMTP`

it will automatically use that `driver details` when you `send mail` and it will send mail using that `SMTP Details`

### To use multiple mail setting you can use this snippet

```
use \Swift_Mailer;
use \Swift_SmtpTransport as SmtpTransport;

// Backup your default mailer so we replace it after
// sending our custom mail
$backup = Mail::getSwiftMailer();

// Setup your gmail mailer
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl');
$transport->setUsername('your_gmail_username');
$transport->setPassword('your_gmail_password');
// other config if needed...

$gmail = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

// Set the mailer as gmail
Mail::setSwiftMailer($gmail);

// Send your message
Mail::send(-- function arguments --);

// Restore your original mailer
Mail::setSwiftMailer($backup);
```

try this and let me know

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this solution does not solve my problem. In my system I use two address when sending. I use plugin for mail setting from admin panel. This plugin overwrites my settings from config. Accordingly, I must specify all the settings for the second mail dynamically so that they overwrite the settings of the first mail that the administrator specifies in the admin panel.
Sorry for my English

Comment: added multiple mail snippet please try to use it and let me know

Comment: Thanks, i understand this idea, I tried it. But now I get other problem.
Connection could not be established with host "my_host' [ #0]" on line 268 of ..\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php. In the answers gave the code.

Comment: may be smtp host error, is smtp host is able to reach/connect from your host pc ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. But this solution does not solve my problem. In my system I use two address when sending. I use plugin for mail setting from admin panel. This plugin overwrites my settings from config. Accordingly, I must specify all the settings for the second mail dynamically so that they overwrite the settings of the first mail that the administrator specifies in the admin panel.
Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

```
$backup = Mail::getSwiftMailer();
    $smtp_host_ip = gethostbyname('my_host');
    $transport = SmtpTransport::newInstance($smtp_host_ip, 465, 'ssl')->setUsername('my_username')->setPassword('my_password');

    $mail = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
    Mail::setSwiftMailer($mail);

    Mail::send($templateMessage, $params, function($message) use ($userSendMes){
       $message->from('my_address_from', 'my_name');
       $message->to($userSendMes["attributes"]["email"], $userSendMes["attributes"]["name"]);
    });
```

all connection settings are correct

Comment: why `gethostbyname('my_host');` is having `my_host` this function will try to convert host-name in to ip address - so don't you think you need to replace it with something `smtp.gmail.com` OR may be add `IP` directly

Comment: as i guess this is throwing error as 'my_host' -> is not able to convert in IP by your system. [ if you are working localy and smtp server is local just add ip 127.0.0.1] ... but i guess `my_host` is not a correct one

Comment: you can see error is also complaining about it 
*Connection could not be established with host "my_host' [ #0]"*